# Can I use an external tool like pdftk in my python script in Windows OS?

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, pdftk

I want to write a Python script in Windows 10 and in the script I want to use an external toolkit like pdftk commands in subprocess.check_call() method

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["pdftk","/home/user/Desktop/Tallyfiles/DrAppalaNaidu.pdf", "output", "/home/user/Desktop/Tallyfiles/manivarma.pdf", "userpw","mani"])
```

the above code worked fine in linux as it has pdftk tool already.
How can I run the same script in Windows ?
Will that pdftk command works properly.

In Ubuntu , I installed pdftk using  " apt-get install pdftk " command.
How to install same pdftk and use in Python script in Windows ?

How to do the same thing in Windows ?
Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Tool `pdftk` should work exactly the same on Windows like on Linux. You only need to install Windows version of [PDFtk-server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) and make sure it's accessible from system `PATH` (or provide full path to executable):

```
subprocess.check_call(["c:/Program Files/PDFtk/pdftk", ...])
```